# Ajax post using json doesnt send data or show error messages

Tags: json, ajax

I'm trying to send contact form data to database and get response with json.

Only error what I get is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

My ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#send').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();

    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo $baseurl;?>/contactus.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {name:name,email:email,phone:phone,subject:subject,message:message},
        success:function(response){ 
          if(response.type == 'error'){ 
              output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
          }else{
             $('#form')[0].reset();
              output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
          }
          $("#contact_results").html(output);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
          console.log(xhr.statusText);
          console.log(textStatus);
          console.log(error);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

My PHP:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');

include('include-global.php');

if($_POST){

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
        print "Can't access directly!";
        exit;
    } 

    $sender_name    = $_POST["name"];
    $sender_email   = $_POST["email"];
    $phone_number   = $_POST["phone"];
    $subject        = $_POST["subject"];
    $message        = $_POST["message"];

    if(strlen($sender_name)<3){
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'First and lastname is too short!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject too short'));
        exit;
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Message too short'));
        exit;
    }

    try{
        $database = new Connection();
        $db = $database->openConnection();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO contact SET name = :name, phone = :phone, subject = :subject, email = :email, message = :message";
        $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
        $qry -> bindParam(':name', $sender_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry -> bindParam(':phone', $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry -> bindParam(':email', $sender_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry -> bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry -> bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry -> execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(!$qry){
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Error.'));
        exit;
    }else{
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thank you '. $sender_name . '.'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

I dont understand what I'am doing wrong...

Code and JSON seems to be correct, I got example from google.
Im using dataType, header content type json but still shows error.

Comment: Post the JSON that is being passed.

Comment: @hungersoft it doesnt post contact form data to database, using ajax dataType json.

Comment: Based on your php code, i think you need to remove the `dataType` from your ajax post request.

Comment: @hungersoft Using json in php, so I must use dataType

Comment: dataType is what you expect *back*; contentType is what you send.

Comment: Im sending Data  and getting back success message or error message

Comment: I wonder if the problem is in using php in the url. I'm not too familiar with php but it seems odd. Try hard coding the url, unless you know it's ok.

Comment: Its Ok because I use same method in another ajax. My example: https://jsfiddle.net/gwtvtL6j/